# Textarea is overlapping with image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a simple layout with an upvote button, but the textarea overlaps with the image.

Here is my sample code:

```css
.my-component-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 248, 1);
}

.my-component-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.my-component-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.my-component-textbox {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.upvote-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.upvote-button {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.view-count {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.upvote-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="margin-bottom: 32px;">
  <header class="p-3 border-bottom sticky-top bg-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
        <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none" style="
          font-size: 30px;
          color: black;
      ">
              Test<sup style="font-size: 12px; color: black; margin-left: 5px;">BETA</sup>
            </a>

        <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
          <li>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/latest" class="nav-link px-2 link-body-emphasis" style="margin-left: 20px;">Text</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container mt-5">

    <!-- IMAGE -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="upvote-section">
          <button id="upvote-button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary upvote-button">
                    <i class="bi bi-arrow-up-square-fill"></i>
                </button>
          <div class="view-count"><span id="view-count">2</span></div>
        </div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt=""
          class="img-fluid ml-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="prompt-text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" rows="4" readonly="">**&lt;https://s.mj.run/wNoQuLDjphY&gt; Darth Vader, cinematic light, Artist Rembrandt Harmenszoon van Rijn, oil painting, high detail, realistic render, octane render, 4k, 8k, realism, cinematic lighting, dramatic --aspect 5:3 --uplight** - Upscaled (Light) by &lt;@803576493681934346&gt;</textarea>
        <button id="copy-prompt" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Copy Prompt</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="bg-white py-3 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p class="text-center">
            ©<span id="currentYear">2023</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

The textarea is overlapping with the image, however I do not understand why?

Any suggestions why I get this error?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Protip: Don't use inline styles or font declarations. They're messy and obsolete and a real pain for all involved.

Comment: Please update the demo to show your problem. What you describe doesn't occur. Also, you've badly misused the `alt` attribute on your image. It's not there for random information. It's an accessibility feature and should contain a description of the image only.

Comment: Not to pile on, but you've written a whole bunch of CSS that could've been handled with Bootstrap classes. I strongly suggest getting more familiar with the library so you aren't reinventing wheels and adding extra effort.

Comment: Thx for your suggestions. I think you used a placeholder image now instead of my test image. However, when using a larger image the textarea overlaps with the image. I also really appreciate your suggestions about bootstrap! I kindly ask you to provide some hints about the fix of the overlapping textarea and image.

Comment: Why haven't you made the image larger? I took another guess based on parameters in the original image URL, but I still don't see a problem. There is no overlap with the textarea element at any screen size. We can't fix what we can't see. Please revise accordingly.

Comment: The issue is the image is overflowing its container. The image width is 100% of its container but the container also has the upvote button, causing overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, set `img { min-width: 0; }` or `img { overflow: hidden; }` - this will help so that the image is compressed properly:

```css
.my-component-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 248, 1);
}

.my-component-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.my-component-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.my-component-textbox {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.upvote-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.upvote-button {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.view-count {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.upvote-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

img {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="margin-bottom: 32px;">
  <header class="p-3 border-bottom sticky-top bg-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
        <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none" style="
          font-size: 30px;
          color: black;
      ">
              Test<sup style="font-size: 12px; color: black; margin-left: 5px;">BETA</sup>
            </a>

        <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
          <li>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/latest" class="nav-link px-2 link-body-emphasis" style="margin-left: 20px;">Text</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container mt-5">

    <!-- IMAGE -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="upvote-section">
          <button id="upvote-button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary upvote-button">
                    <i class="bi bi-arrow-up-square-fill"></i>
                </button>
          <div class="view-count"><span id="view-count">2</span></div>
        </div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt=""
          class="img-fluid ml-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="prompt-text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" rows="4" readonly="">**&lt;https://s.mj.run/wNoQuLDjphY&gt; Darth Vader, cinematic light, Artist Rembrandt Harmenszoon van Rijn, oil painting, high detail, realistic render, octane render, 4k, 8k, realism, cinematic lighting, dramatic --aspect 5:3 --uplight** - Upscaled (Light) by &lt;@803576493681934346&gt;</textarea>
        <button id="copy-prompt" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Copy Prompt</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="bg-white py-3 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p class="text-center">
            ©<span id="currentYear">2023</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```